# Zabbix Agent 6.0

Tags: server, zabbix, agent

I have a problem with Zabbix 6.0 LTS! Where  i install zabbix agent 6.0 in this server! I have a error invalid argument:

In Zabbix Server 6.0 LTS  its okay,but in zabbix agent 6.0 server i have a this error:

check 'vfs.file.contents["/sys/class/net/eth0/speed"]' is not supported: Cannot read from file: read /sys/class/net/eth0/speed: invalid argument

I dont have any idea also i try cat more commands for /sys/class/net/eth0/speed in file speed the error also invalid argument
P.S: File Exist! -r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Feb  1 16:25 /sys/class/net/eth0/speed

Comment: the user zabbix, which is the default user to run the zabbix-agent service, has not enough priviledges to read that path, or the path doesn't exists anymore because eth0 has been removed or renamed

Comment: @IronBishop Hi! The first i have a root user and all priviliges its okey also all files or path are exist!  (-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4.0K Feb  1 16:25 /sys/class/net/eth0/speed)